# Sequential Sampling

Tags: python, sampling, normal-distribution

To sample from N(1,2) with sample size 100 and calculating the mean of this sample we can do this:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.random.normal(1, 2, 100)
mean = np.mean(s)
```

Now if we want to produce 10000 samples and save mean of each of them we can do:

```
sample_means = []
for x in range(10000):
    sample = np.random.normal(1, 2, 100)
    sample_means.append (sample.mean())
```

How can I do it when we want to sample sequentially from N(1,2) and estimate the distribution mean sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you meant accumulative

```
sample = np.random.normal(1,2,(10000, 100))
sample_mean = []
for i,_ in enumerate(sample):
    sample_mean.append(sample[:i+1,:].ravel().mean())
```

Then `sample_mean` contains the accumulative samples mean

```
sample_mean[:10]
[1.1185342714036368,
 1.3270808654923423,
 1.3266440422140355,
 1.2542028664103761,
 1.179358517854582,
 1.1224645540064788,
 1.1416887857272255,
 1.1156887336750463,
 1.0894328800573165,
 1.0878896099712452]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe list comprehension?

```py
sample_means = [np.random.normal(1, 2, 100).mean() for i in range(10000)]
```

**TIP** Use lower case to name variables in Python